# Как вернуть строку на GET запрос, по частям, заранее не известной длинны?

Tags: delphi, http

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
myStr := '';
myStr := Calc();
RangeStart := 0;
RangeEnd := Length(myStr);
AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 206;
AResponseInfo.ContentLength := RangeEnd + 1;
AResponseInfo.ContentRangeStart := RangeStart;
AResponseInfo.ContentRangeEnd := RangeEnd;
AResponseInfo.ContentText := myStr;
AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'application/json;charset=UTF-8';
AResponseInfo.WriteContent;
for i := 1 to 10 do
begin
    myStr := '';
    myStr := Calc();
    RangeStart := RangeEnd;
    RangeEnd := RangeEnd + Length(myStr);
    AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 206;
    AResponseInfo.ContentLength := RangeEnd + 1;
    AResponseInfo.ContentRangeStart := RangeStart;
    AResponseInfo.ContentRangeEnd := RangeEnd;
    AResponseInfo.ContentText := myStr;
    AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'application/json;charset=UTF-8';
    AResponseInfo.WriteContent;
end
RangeStart := RangeEnd;
RangeEnd := RangeEnd + 1;
AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
AResponseInfo.ContentLength := RangeEnd;
AResponseInfo.ContentRangeStart := RangeStart;
AResponseInfo.ContentRangeEnd := RangeEnd;
AResponseInfo.ContentText := #0;
AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'application/json;charset=UTF-8';
AResponseInfo.WriteContent;
```

соединение закрывается после получения первого куска и первого символа со второго куска.

Пробовал ContentLength сделать 10000, но тогда страничка ожидает ответа, хотя все данные отправлены.
Подскажите как быть?

Comment: Знакомьтесь: [Transfer-Encoding: chunked](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

Comment: @zed не выходит, может напишите правильную отправку первого блока

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uses ..., IdGlobal;    
...
procedure TForm1.HTTPSServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
    myStr: String;
begin
    if LowerCase(ARequestInfo.URI) = '/myrequest' then
    begin
        AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
        AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'application/json;charset=UTF-8';
        AResponseInfo.TransferEncoding := 'chunked';
        AResponseInfo.WriteHeader;            
        myStr := Calc();
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(IntToHex(Length(myStr), 8));
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(ToBytes(myStr), Length(myStr));
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn;
        for i := 1 to 10 do
        begin                
            myStr := Calc();
            AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(IntToHex(Length(myStr), 8));
            AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(ToBytes(myStr), Length(myStr));
            AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn;
        end
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('0');
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: А ваши строки точно не более 16 байт? Если нет, то вторым параметром функции `IntToHex` надо задать число по-больше, например - 8. Плюс, почитайте варнинги и хинты компилятора, он вам должен подсказать, что строки `myStr := '';` в этом коде не нужны.

Comment: @zed нет ни 1 варнинги и хинты, это в примере так получилось. на счет размера прочту, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Соберите сначала весь ответ в одну локальную переменную (строку) и потом отправьте его за один раз.

У вас в цикле ошибка:

```
RangeEnd := RangeEnd + Length(iStrig); // должно быть myStr вместо iStrig ?
```

Comment: это опечатка в вопросе, проблема не в этом

Comment: А что мешает собрать сначала весь ответ или сделать функцию, которая его вернет?

Comment: Собрать весь ответ займет от 1 до 5 минут, а так можно уже просматривать то что готово, удобно